# How to make an Image Icon with a button to change the image like google:

Tags: image, flutter, dart, icons, flutter-layout

I wanna create, in my Profile Screen, an user's profile photo rounded with a button, or a something creative to change this photo like google:

[image: google]

But what I have now is this:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 75,
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 70,
    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/default.png'),
  )
),
```

How can I add a button like in the google example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Stack` you can put icon on top of the avatar and at a specific position.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 75,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 70,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/default.png'),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 1,
          right: 1,
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(
                    50,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(2, 4),
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(
                      0.3,
                    ),
                    blurRadius: 3,
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack widget with Positioned as its child widget.

Comment: And does you know how to make a rounded button?

Comment: Not necessary that photo icon is a button.. You can wrap that image with InkWell and add onTap() method to implement the same functionality on that you would have written on button click.

Comment: This should be a comment.